# Is it possible to inject a token after another token?

Tags: input, token-lists

Something like:

- *If* 
  next token is some token that artificially creates a page break (e.g. `\newpage`, `\clearpage`
- *Then*
  inject something after it
- *Else*
  inject something before it

I want to modify `\input` to provide visual cues in the PDF. A "problem" appears when my `\input` starts with a page break. It is not *really* a problem, because my injection is always right where I would expect it. I would just prefer my injection to be shown on the start of the new page.

## Define Injection(s)

In this case, two TikZ Overlays, but it could be the letter "b", for example.

```
% TikZ Overlay
\makeatletter
\newcounter{mac@input-tracker}% for unique tikz coordinate/node labels
\tikzstyle{inputtext}=[xshift=2mm,orange,font=\tiny]
\def\tikzbegininput{% Injection before input
      \tikz [remember picture] \coordinate  (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker});
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [anchor=south west,inputtext] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}) at
            (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker} -| current page.west) {Begin \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}};
        \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.east) --
                                           (current page.east |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker});
        \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange,xshift=5mm,->] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.south west) --
                                                         ($(input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west)+(0,-5mm)$);
        \draw [line width=2mm,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west) --
                                  (current page.west |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\def\tikzendinput{% Injection after input
\tikz [remember picture] \coordinate (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end);
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node [anchor=north west,inputtext] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end) at
      (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end -| current page.west) {End \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}};
      \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.east) -- (current page.east |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end);
      \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange,xshift=5mm,->] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.north west) -- ($(input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.west)+(0,5mm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

}%
\makeatother
```

## Redefine input to include injection

```
% Redefine input to accept TikZ overlay injection
    \makeatletter
    \AtBeginDocument{% Redefine \input
      \let\latex@input\input%
      \newcommand\red@input[1]{%
          \stepcounter{mac@input-tracker}% add one to unique tikz label counter
          \protected@edef\tmp{#1}
          \tikzbegininput % inject tikz overlay at begin input
          \IfFileExists{#1}{% Added some failsafe logic so doc still compiles when input missing (usually not good unless you enjoy reading logs)
            \latex@input{#1}% actual input
          }{}
        {% Does not exist
          \typeout{RegexFindableErrorPrefix: Missing file "#1"}% for error report (also allows document to compile, TikZ overlays make missing file visible in PDF
        }
        \tikzendinput % inject tikz overlay at end input
      }
      \let\input\red@input% Set \input to new definition
    }%
\makeatother
```

## External File Contents

`lipsum.tex`

```
\newpage\lipsum[1]
```

## Put It All Together

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text from elegant Latin
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Redefine input to accept TikZ overlay injection
    \makeatletter
    \AtBeginDocument{% Redefine \input
      \let\latex@input\input%
      \newcommand\red@input[1]{%
          \stepcounter{mac@input-tracker}% add one to unique tikz label counter
          \protected@edef\tmp{#1}
          \tikzbegininput % inject tikz overlay at begin input
          \IfFileExists{#1}{% Added some failsafe logic so doc still compiles when input missing (usually not good unless you enjoy reading logs)
            \latex@input{#1}% actual input
          }{}
        {% Does not exist
          \typeout{RegexFindableErrorPrefix: Missing file "#1"}% for error report (also allows document to compile, TikZ overlays make missing file visible in PDF
        }
        \tikzendinput % inject tikz overlay at end input
      }
      \let\input\red@input% Set \input to new definition
    }%
\makeatother

% TikZ Overlay
\makeatletter
\newcounter{mac@input-tracker}% for unique tikz coordinate/node labels
\tikzstyle{inputtext}=[xshift=2mm,orange,font=\tiny]
\def\tikzbegininput{% Injection before input
      \tikz [remember picture] \coordinate  (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker});
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [anchor=south west,inputtext] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}) at
            (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker} -| current page.west) {Begin \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}};
        \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.east) --
                                           (current page.east |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker});
        \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange,xshift=5mm,->] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.south west) --
                                                         ($(input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west)+(0,-5mm)$);
        \draw [line width=2mm,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west) --
                                  (current page.west |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\def\tikzendinput{% Injection after input
\tikz [remember picture] \coordinate (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end);
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node [anchor=north west,inputtext] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end) at
      (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end -| current page.west) {End \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}};
      \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.east) -- (current page.east |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end);
      \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange,xshift=5mm,->] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.north west) -- ($(input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.west)+(0,5mm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \input{lipsum.tex}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

## Output

This output is without `\newpage` in lipsum.tex for creating a compact illustration.

[image]

Maybe there is a way with `\futurelet` and `\afterassignment`?

Comment: << *A "problem" appears when my \input starts with a page break* >> is the page break here  because of `\newpage` like command or because of Tex's page breaking algorithm?

Comment: @touhami Good question. By "artificial", I mean not the TeX page-breaking algorithm, rather an explicit break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution. We redefine the command `\InputIfFileExists`

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\long\def \InputIfFileExists#1#2{%
\stepcounter{mac@input-tracker}%
\protected@edef\tmp{#1}%
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {#2\@addtofilelist{#1}\expandafter\mtt\@@input \@filef@und \tikzendinput}}}
```

change `\@@input \@filef@und -->\expandafter\mtt\@@input \@filef@und \tikzendinput`

the new command `\mtt` is defined using the [xstring](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package

```
\newcommand{\mtt}[1]{%
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
{\newpage}{%
\let\mtnewpage\newpage
\newpage
\def\newpage{\let\newpage\mtnewpage}\tikzbegininput}%
{\clearpage}{\let\mtclearpage\clearpage
\clearpage
\def\clearpage{\let\clearpage\mtclearpage}\tikzbegininput}}%
[\tikzbegininput#1]}
```

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text from elegant Latin
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{xstring}
\normalexpandarg

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mtt}[1]{%
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
{\newpage}{%
\let\mtnewpage\newpage
\newpage
\def\newpage{\let\newpage\mtnewpage}\tikzbegininput}%
{\clearpage}{\let\mtclearpage\clearpage
\clearpage
\def\clearpage{\let\clearpage\mtclearpage}\tikzbegininput}}%
[\tikzbegininput#1]}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\long\def \InputIfFileExists#1#2{%
\stepcounter{mac@input-tracker}%
\protected@edef\tmp{#1}%
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {#2\@addtofilelist{#1}\expandafter\mtt\@@input \@filef@und \tikzendinput}}}

% TikZ Overlay
\newcounter{mac@input-tracker}% for unique tikz coordinate/node labels
\tikzstyle{inputtext}=[xshift=2mm,orange,font=\tiny]
\def\tikzbegininput{% Injection before input
      \tikz [remember picture] \coordinate  (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker});
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [anchor=south west,inputtext] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}) at
            (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker} -| current page.west) {Begin \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}};
        \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.east) --
                                           (current page.east |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker});
        \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange,xshift=5mm,->] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.south west) --
                                                         ($(input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west)+(0,-5mm)$);
        \draw [line width=2mm,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west) --
                                  (current page.west |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}.west);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\def\tikzendinput{% Injection after input
\tikz [remember picture] \coordinate (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end);
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node [anchor=north west,inputtext] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end) at
      (input-tracker-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end -| current page.west) {End \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}};
      \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.east) -- (current page.east |- input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end);
      \draw [thin,densely dotted,orange,xshift=5mm,->] (input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.north west) -- ($(input-tracker-text-\the\value{mac@input-tracker}-end.west)+(0,5mm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \input{lipsum}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

---

**Update: explanation**

```
\IfStrEqCase{string}{%
    {string1}{excute code 1}%
    {string2}{excute code 2}%
    {string3}{excute code 3}%
    ...
    {stringN}{excute code N}%
    [〈other cases code〉]
```

From [xstring doc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring)

> Tests successively if 〈string〉 is equal to 〈string1〉, 〈string2〉, etc.
>   Comparison is made with `\IfStrEq` (see above). If the test number i is
>   positive (the 〈string〉 matches 〈string i〉), the macro runs 〈code i〉
>   and ends. If all tests fail, the macro runs the optional 〈other cases
>   code〉, if present.

in our case `string=#1` is the first token in the inputed file, `string1`,  `string2`,... are `\newpage`, `\clearpage` ...

Comment: This is a cool answer. Could you explain how you are capturing all cases of "artificially"-created new pages? `\newpage, \clearpage` etc.?

Comment: I will try, this is just example, one should complete the code by adding `\cleardoublepage` and my be `\pagebreak`

Comment: @macmadness86 please see the update.